# Touchpad doesn't work under ubuntu20.04 Kernel 5.15.0-92-generic

Tags: 20.04, mouse, touchpad

I recently installed ubuntu20.04 on my Lenovo Y9000p The touchpad never worked under Ubuntu but worked well under Windows.
Firstly I tried xinput list and got nothing related to my touchpad.

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SINO WEALTH Legion M5 Wireless Gaming Mouse_2.4G  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SINO WEALTH Legion M5 Wireless Gaming Mouse_2.4G Keyboard id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Keyboard  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Wireless Radio Control    id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SINO WEALTH Legion M5 Wireless Gaming Mouse_2.4G Keyboard id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Keyboard  id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Then I tried to list the i2c devices, but I got nothing as well.

```
$ i2cdetect  -l
```

```
$ ls /dev/i2c*
ls: cannot access '/dev/i2c*': No such file or directory
```

I have no idea what happened with my touchpad QAQ.

Comment: What's `sudo dmesg | grep Touchpad`?

Comment: @DanielT It returns nothing.